# Simple tensorflow/keras model with one hot vector output gives error message

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to make a simple multi-layer perceptron classifier to begin with, before elaborating on the model, however I am having trouble matching the output layer to the labelled data. The most concise code that shows the behavior is:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Generate example dataset
X = np.random.rand(1000, 1)  # One-dimensional input
y = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(1000,))  # Random integer labels
X_val = np.random.rand(1000, 1)  # One-dimensional input
y_val = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(1000,))  # Random integer labels

# Convert integer labels to one-hot vectors
y_one_hot = tf.one_hot(y, depth=10)  # Assuming 10 classes
y_val_one_hot = tf.one_hot(y_val, depth=10)

# Create a zipped dataset
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, y_one_hot))
val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_val, y_val_one_hot))

# Define batch size
batch_size = 32

# Shuffle and batch the training dataset
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=100).batch(batch_size)

# Define the MLP model
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(1,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')  # Output layer with softmax activation for one-hot vectors
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Precision()])

# Train the model
model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=10, validation_data=val_dataset)
```

The error message given is

```
File "/home/vboxuser/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/backend.py", line 5573, in categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)

    ValueError: Shapes (10, 1) and (1, 10) are incompatible
```

I have tried using tf.transpose and tf.reshape to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the `validation_data` must be one of the following:

- A tuple `(x_val, y_val)` of Numpy arrays or tensors.
- A tuple `(x_val, y_val, val_sample_weights)` of NumPy arrays.
- A `tf.data.Dataset`.
- A Python generator or `keras.utils.Sequence` returning
  `(inputs, targets)` or `(inputs, targets, sample_weights)`.

The data created from `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` does not match any of the options given above.

The best case scenario is to simply use a tuple.  Thus have:

```
  val_dataset = (X_val, y_val_one_hot)
```

and run your program:

---

Test your program:

```
# Generate example dataset
X = np.random.rand(1000, 1)  # One-dimensional input
y = X.ravel()*1000//100  # integer labels
X_val = np.random.rand(1000, 1)  # One-dimensional input
y_val = (X_val.ravel()*1000//100)  # integer labels

# Convert integer labels to one-hot vectors
y_one_hot = tf.one_hot(y, depth=10)  # Assuming 10 classes
y_val_one_hot = tf.one_hot(y_val, depth=10)

# Create a zipped dataset
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, y_one_hot))
val_dataset = (X_val, y_val_one_hot) # THE CHANGE

# Define batch size
batch_size = 32

# Shuffle and batch the training dataset
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=100).batch(batch_size)

# Define the MLP model
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(1,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')  # Output layer with softmax activation for one-hot vectors
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Precision()])

# Train the model
model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=20, validation_data = val_dataset)
```

Comment: there goes my hero